# Make SQL query optimize to return result faster

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table with millions of records. I want to fetch the top 10 earners of the current date (calculating by grouping user_id and adding `earnings` field value of the same user) and I have created the below query for that.

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(earnings) AS earn
FROM statistics
WHERE created LIKE "2022-03-15%"
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY earn DESC
limit 10
```

The query is giving the expected result, but the problem is that it's taking around 90 seconds to do processing and all.

Is there any modification possible in the above query to make it faster to get results within 10-15 seconds or less?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: Using LIKE on a date column does not sound efficient, assuming it is a DATETIME column??

Comment: You start by showing us the schema for this table

Comment: If you want your queries to run quickly, then yes you need indexing. That's why indexes exist. Adding 50,000 rows to an 8,000,000-row table is not much at all. Go read at http://use-the-index-luke.com/ like I mentioned above.

Comment: Thats not the schema, try showing us a Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: I have, no reason why we should not ask for the schema, woudn't be the first time an OP had no idea what was going on

Comment: Please do not deface your question. This is not allowed, nor should it be allowed, as you're making the efforts of the answerer pointless and futile.

Comment: @Kelly - Don't worry about votes. Focus on improving the question so that others can help you find an answer.  To best help you, please post the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;`, as others asked.

Comment: @SOS and HovercraftFullOfEels, I have added the table schema.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - True.  `LIKE` with a date or datetime must convert to varchar, thereby making it not sargable, hence preventing the use of the obvious index.  But it is handy!

Comment: @AndyLester - Can't solve _this_ query with an index.  Instead, reformulate the query to may the index usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE created LIKE "2022-03-15%"
```

-->

```
WHERE created >= "2022-03-15"
  AND created  < "2022-03-15" + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

The former is not "sargable" because it must turn a `DATETIME` into a string to do the `LIKE`.  The latter is likely to use index `idx_created_userid` very effectively.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I was also able to solve this by using BETWEEN Operator. You can check my answer too :)

Comment: If you want to capture the full day, the approach above is simpler than using BETWEEN.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any modification possible in the above query to make it faster to get results within 10-15 seconds or less?

No, there is nothing you can change in the query that will make up for the lack of indexes on the table. Every time you run that query, MySQL has to look at every single row in the table, which you said is about 8,000,000 rows. Indexes make it so that MySQL only needs to look at the small subset of rows that are relevant.

Comment: As I said, every day around 50k+ new records add to the table. Isn't it like indexes are like caching or indexes do search on updated data?

Comment: Indexes do search on the updated data. They are updated every time you INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE a row. You will not lose functionality by adding indexes.

Comment: It's not going to help with needing a table scan, but if `created` is a datetime column, `LIKE` is the wrong operator. Use date values with a range search ie. `Col >= {BeginDateAtMidnight}' and  `< {DayAfterEndDateAtMidnight}`